# How to change range of values with another range of values in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change range of values with another range of values in VBA. I tried following code but i got error: Type missmatch

```
Sub ChangeOneToGrade()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select a range", Type:=8)
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng2 = rng
Dim Count As Integer
For Each cell In rng.Rows
 If cell.Value = 1 Then
 cell.Value = rng2.Offset(0, Count)
 End If
Count = Count + 1
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: `rng2 = rng.Row` is going to give a `Long` so you can't set that in your `Range object` change `Dim rng2 As Range` for `Dim rng2 As Long`

Comment: I changed that and not I got another error:  compile error Type missmatch

Comment: Read my edited comment, I noticed on a second look the other error. Even better, take off the `.row` when setting the range....

Comment: I updated the code and now i got error : ınvalid qualifier

Comment: `rng2`m ust be a `Range` object, then you need to `Set rng2 = rng` which is a bit absurd... but you are mixing types here.

Comment: I updated the code and now after inputting the range it gives the error 'type missmatch'

Comment: You are still lacking the declaration `Dim cell As Range` use `Option Explicit` on the top of your module, which will force you to declare all your variables.

Comment: `cell.Value = rng2.Offset(0, Count)`: `rng2` is of type `Long`. It's not an object so has no methods attached to it. Also, you are trying to use `Count` before you have assigned a value to it. **Tips**: it is highly recommended that you don't use reserved words (**cell**) as your variable names (if you have to, then change it to something like: `oCell`). Also, `Option Explicit` is your friend

Comment: I am slightly confused. What are you trying to achieve here? What is the role of `Count` here? I know what `Count` is doint but my question is `Why`. What are you exactly trying to achieve with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve - replace every occurrence of `1` in `rng` with the corresponding value in `rng2`. I have added some default data, and  default ranges to the `InputBox`s.

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 7
    Cells(1, i) = Int(Rnd * 2)
    Cells(2, i) = i + 1
Next i
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select a range", Default:="a1:g1", Type:=8)
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng2 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select a range", Default:="a2:g2", Type:=8)
Dim Count As Integer: Count = 1
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = 1 Then
        cell.Value = rng2.Columns(Count)
    End If
    Count = Count + 1
Next cell
```

Your 'Type mismatch' comes from `rng.Rows` returns a collection of rows, and so `cell` was iterating through rows and not cells, and so `cell.Value` had no meaning.

Comment: True that was one Type Mismatch. I got another when testing on a range that had numbers formatted as text (apparently).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't ideal, but it should get you on the right track. `Cells(Row, Column)` is used. You can swap Row & Column, see what happens.

```
Sub ChangeOneToGrade()
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select a range", Type:=8)
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng2 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select another range", Type:=8)

Dim cnt As Long: cnt = 1
Dim celll As Range  'extra l on purpose
For Each celll In rng1
    'Do 1 IF with "And" and you'll get same Type-Mismatch
    If IsNumeric(celll.Value) Then
        If celll.Value = 1 Then
            rng2.Cells(cnt, 1).Value = 1
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```